# Emacs on Windows opens emtpy buffer when started from script

Tags: bash, emacs, git-bash, org-mode

## Background

I'm rewriting my `newNote` script and I'm using the runemacs.exe *Windows* instead of calling the binary directly like I've done in the past. Previously I'd have the launching terminal hanging out in the background and I realized that runemacs.exe avoids that annoyance.

## Issue:

The script works from a raw file point of view but when emacs launches I get an empty buffer where I expect to see a title and some TODO tags defined. If I open the `.org` file directly I see the contents match what I'm expecting. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE_NOTES_DIR="${USER_DESKTOP}/Notes"
CURRENT_DATE=`date "+%Y_%m_%d_%s"`
TODO_OPTIONS='TODO InProgress(i) Rejected(R) | BackBurner(B) DONE(D) Cancelled(c)'

function spaceToUnderscore()
{
    RESULT="`echo "$@" | sed 's/ /_/g'`"
}


function getPromptResponseEscaped()
{
    read -p "$@" answer
    spaceToUnderscore $answer
}

getPromptResponseEscaped "Which Project is this for?: "
Project=$RESULT

read -p "What title for this new note?: " user_title
spaceToUnderscore $user_title
Title=$RESULT

Folder="${BASE_NOTES_DIR}/${Project}/${Title}"

if [ ! -d $Folder ]
then
    mkdir -p $Folder
fi

fileName="${CURRENT_DATE}_${Title}.org"
filePath="${Folder}/${fileName}"
touch $filePath && \
echo "#+TITLE: ${user_title}" >> $filePath && \
echo "#+TODO: ${TODO_OPTIONS}" >> $filePath && \
sync && \
"C:\Program Files\Emacs\x86_64\bin\runemacs.exe" "$fileName"
```

## Notes:

### Executing

`USER_DESKTOP` needs to be defined either as an env variable or as a new line before running this code.

### Bash version

`GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`

Comment: You're writing into `$filePath` but opening `$fileName`

Comment: Just change `$fileName` to `$filePath` on the last line.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Glad we have multiple sets of eyes in this world. Thanks for the quick response!